# Регулярки c# reg mark

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

bool CheckMark(string mark)
Функция проверяет переданный номерной знак в формате a999aa999 (латинскими буквами) и возвращает true или false в зависимости от правильности номерного знака.
Создать текстовый файл test.txt с 20 исходными верными и неверными данными для проверки работы функции.
Написать программу, которая для каждой строки этого файла произведет проверку регистрационного номера и выведет на экран результат в виде: номер – true/false

Возвращает только самый первый правильный номер, после этого прекращает работу. Хотя в файле присутствуют и другие правильные номера

```
public static bool CheckMark(string mark)
        {
            string[] line = mark.Split(' ');
            Regex number = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$");
            for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
            {
                if (number.IsMatch(line[i]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line[i]);
                    // return true;
                }
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
=======================================
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            REG_MARK r = new REG_MARK();
            string mark = @"testBilet1.txt";
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(mark, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
            string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
            REG_MARK.CheckMark(s);
        }
```

Comment: `return true;` из кода удалите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя на первой итерации цикла осуществляется выход из метода:

```
return true;
```

По смыслу не вижу причины что либо возвращать из метода, сделай его void и удали оба return.

Но лучше сделать тип возвращаемого параметра int, а в цикле посчитать кол-во вхождений номера в файле и возвращать это число. Как то так:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ExcelReaderWriter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = "a999aa999 a999aa999 a999aa99!!!!";
            var separator = ' ';
            var mask = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$");

            Console.WriteLine($"Кол-во номеров: {CountMask(text, separator, mask)}");
        }

        static int CountMask(string text, char separator, Regex mask)
            => text.Split(separator).Count(e => mask.IsMatch(e));
    }
}
```

Консоль:

Кол-во номеров: 2